# Decreasing Rows and Column of Raster file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working on urbanization modelling.

While processing i need to have the columns and rows of the raster file less than 100. But my raster file has more than 2000 rows and columns. So, I re sampled it but after that the clarity was too poor.

What can be the other techniques to reduce its number without compromising too much of clarity?

Answer (score 2):

By reducing the number of rows and columns you are inherently reducing the quality of the raster. The fewer "pixels" or cells you have the less detail you will have to work with.

If you are adamant that you want to work with 100 rows and columns, I would suggest you look at your current cell size and calculate the distance you would need to encompass the 100 x 100 working area. Then using the "Data management -> Sampling -> Create Fishnet" toolbox, create a fishnet polygon with the length and width you would need to encompass your desired working area.

Using the Spatial Analyst, Extract by mask tool you can then extract the raster based on your fishnet. The extracted raster will be the size you want and you can process it from there.

Due to this being a timely process, I would suggest you look at setting up a model in Model Builder or using Python to automate much of this.